# Why doesn't the margin-bottom property work?

Tags: css, html, margin

[The error can be found in this image...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iki5.jpg) I need the white-colored list in the image to go up by several pixels, but when I try to use the margin-bottom function, a space appears between the grey-colored list (id is leftmenu) and the white-colored list (id is newsmenu) instead. Is there any way I can fix this issue? I've tried using several code from answers to similar questions on this website, but even that doesn't seem to work.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="developer.manifest">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
<title>Website</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Website</h1>
        </header>

        <nav id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="menuitem"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li class="menuitem"><a href="index.html">STUFF</a></li>
                <li class="menuitem"><a href="index.html">STUFF</a></li>
                <li class="menuitem"><a href="index.html">STUFF</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

            <nav id="leftmenu">
            <h4>Random sentence.</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">List</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">List</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">List</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">List</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">List</a></li>>
                </ul>
                <br></br>
            </nav>

            <img class="displayed" src="images/kurtar.jpg" alt="Stuff">

            <nav id="rightmenu">
            <h4>Random Sentence.</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">List</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">List</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">List</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">List</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">List</a></li>
                </ul>
                <br></br>
            </nav>

            <!--This is the list that I want margin-bottom to move up.-->
            <div id="newsmenu">
            <h4>Latest MOCing News:</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li>[NEW] 5/7/2016: Website undergoing development...</li>
                </ul>
                <br></br>
            </div>

    </div><!--container end-->

    <div class="clear"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

body{
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:"Verdana";
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    background-image:url(../images/background.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

a{
    text-decoration:none;
}

p{
    margin:10px 0;
}

/* Main styles */
#container{
    width:1000px;
    overflow:auto;
}

.displayed {
    margin: 15px 0 250px 40px;
    border-width:7px;
    border-color:#606060;
    border-style:outset;
}

header{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:"Georgia";
    width:98.6%;
    height:85px;
    background:#ffffff;
    border-width:7px;
    border-color:#DFDFDF;
    border-style:outset;
    margin-top:20px;
    padding-top:15px;
}

header h1{
    color:#D4AF37;
    font-size:43px;
    padding:10px 0 0 0;
    text-align:center;
}

aside {
    color:white;
}

nav#menu{
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    width:98.5%;
    height:30px;
    background:#494949;
    border-width:7px;
    border-color:#606060;
    border-style:outset;
    margin-top:15px;
}

nav#menu ul{
    padding:0;
    padding-top:7px;
    width:960px;
}

nav#menu li{
    padding:0;
    display:inline;
}

nav#menu li a,#menu li a:visited{
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:0 13px 0 13px;
}

nav#leftmenu{
    margin-top:15px;
    width:190px;
    float:left;
    background:#C0C0C0;
    border-width:7px;
    border-color:#B6B6B6;
    border-style:outset;
    padding: 15px 20px 0 10px;
}

nav#leftmenu ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
}

nav#leftmenu  li{
    list-style:none;
    padding:15px 0 8px 0;
    border-bottom:1px dashed #000000;
}

nav#leftmenu a,nav#leftmenu a:visited{
    color:#000000;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:12px;
}

nav#leftmenu h4{
    color:#000000;
    padding:0;
    padding-bottom:8px;
    border-bottom:#000000 solid 2px;
    font-size:12px;
}

nav#rightmenu{
    margin-top:15px;
    width:190px;
    float:right;
    background:#C0C0C0;
    border-width:7px;
    border-color:#B6B6B6;
    border-style:outset;
    padding: 15px 20px 0 10px;
}

nav#rightmenu ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
}

nav#rightmenu  li{
    list-style:none;
    padding:15px 0 8px 0;
    border-bottom:1px dashed #000000;
}

nav#rightmenu a,nav#rightmenu a:visited{
    color:#000000;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:12px;
}

nav#rightmenu h4{
    color:#000000;
    padding:0;
    padding-bottom:8px;
    border-bottom:#000000 solid 2px;
    font-size:12px;
}

div#newsmenu{
    width:190px;
    float:left;
    background:#ffffff;
    border-width:7px;
    border-color:#DFDFDF;
    border-style:outset;
    padding: 15px 20px 0 10px;
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:200px;
}

div#newsmenu ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
}

div#newsmenu  li{
    list-style:none;
    padding:15px 0 8px 0;
    border-bottom:1px dashed #000000;
    color:blue;
    font-size:11px;
}

div#newsmenu a,div#newsmenu a:visited{
    color:#000000;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:12px;
}

div#newsmenu h4{
    color:#000000;
    padding:0;
    padding-bottom:8px;
    border-bottom:#000000 solid 2px;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

Comment: why not use the `margin-top` property?

Comment: Which list exactly? Your question is not clear enough. Also you have some syntax errors (the `br` tag does not need to be closed) - see jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/h1g20e8g/

Comment: use `margin: 10px auto` to adjust the margin of top and bottom.

Comment: ul {
    margin-top: -10px;
}

Comment: seemes you wanted to add another element below the `Latest MOCing News:` box

Comment: To Aziz: Thanks for notifying me of syntax errors! I was talking about the list with the id newsmenu.

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin-top` instead, like all the rest of the objects in your document

```
div#newsmenu {
        width: 190px;
        float: left;
        background: #ffffff;
        border-width: 7px;
        border-color: #DFDFDF;
        border-style: outset;
        padding: 15px 20px 0 10px;
        position: relative;
        /*margin-bottom: 200px; Delete this one*/
        margin-top:15px;
    }
```

This will align your object to the rest. To make it go up more by several pixels, lower the `15px` as much as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about this space? (see below image)
[image]

If yes, then remove `margin-top: 15px` from nav#leftmenu, or make it `0`.

```
nav#leftmenu {
   background: #c0c0c0 none repeat scroll 0 0;
   border-color: #b6b6b6;
   border-style: outset;
   border-width: 7px;
   float: left;
   margin-top: 0; /* Changes needs to be make here. */
   padding: 15px 20px 0 10px;
   width: 190px;
}
```

Comment: Actually, no I am not talking about that space. Thanks for being willing to help, though!